# How to retrieve system attributes of account entity using IOrganisationservice ,.retrieve method

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a requirement where I need to retrieve the system attributes of an entity.

```
                           ColumnSet cset = new ColumnSet(true);
                           cset.AllColumns = true;

                           Entity capconnect=(Entity)_servicecapconnect.Retrieve("account",cc.Key,cset);
```

When I do retrieve the entity capconnect has only the custom attributes of account.But I am interested in getting attributes like "telephone1" "address1_line1" which are system attributes of account entity.

I looked in the database the account entity has 60 columns but the attributes retrieved are only 46 which are all the custom attributes.

I appreciate your inputs.
-Akila

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the properties, which are not present in the entity, don't have a value. This is normal as the response will only include the fields which contain values due to performance reasons.

Therefore the response won't be bloated with null values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guarantee that the system attributes contain data.I have looked in to the database.